# Exce VBA Remove leading/ lagging space in column headers after exporting to CSV

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make my VBA code export an excel Worksheet to a `CSV` file.

All works well except that it caused leading and lagging spaces in the first couple  column headers. I have tried trimming the cells before export but it hasn't helped.

Here is my code:

```
Sub export()
    
    'Trim the headers before export
    temp = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sample").Range("A1:ZZ1"))
    For i = 1 To temp
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sample").Cells(1, i) = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sample").Cells(1, i))
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    fpath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    fName = "sample_Adjusted"
    Filename = fpath & "\" & fName & ".csv"
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sample").Copy
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename, xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    
End Sub
```

How can I get rid of those spaces?

Comment: Why do you have `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: it's to skip error notification if a file names sample.csv already exists and is open in the same folder. It can be removed

Comment: Are you sure you have spaces and not some other "space-like" character(s) like Chr(160) (non-breaking space) which would not be removed by `Trim()`?  I've never heard of "save as CSV" adding content such as spaces.

Comment: Tim: There seems to none of that.

Comment: How are you viewing the content of the generated CSV file?   Can you provide a sample worksheet which we can use to replicate the problem?

Comment: Here is the link to a sample file with the macro. You can see spaces in cell B1 and C1 on the 'sample_Adjusted.csv' file  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I505_Cir3Y0SuNOtrPKHYHdHpz9vP359/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110343012185501628168&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: When I download that worksheet, it does **not** demonstrate a leading space.  You can see the first character in those cells by using the formula `=LEFT(B1)`  or `=CODE(B1)` to return the character, or the character code of the first letter.  The *appearance* in the cell of a leading space is due to the *formatting* applied to that cell.  Format it as `General` and the appearance will change.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Did you run the macro in the workbook? You will see spaces in the CSV output

Comment: I would expect that.  When you save an Excel file as CSV, it is the `.text` property of the Range object that gets saved.  So it is translating the space induced by your formatting into a real space in the CSV.  If you want to eliminate that space, you will need to change the formatting.  eg:  `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sample").Cells(1, i).NumberFormat = "@"`.  Of course, depending on whether you need that leading space format in your Excel file, you may want to do this on a temporary sheet or book.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you for your reply but changing the formatting didnt work either. I tried 
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sample").Cells(1, i).NumberFormat = "@"` right before `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sample").Cells(1, i) = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sample").Cells(1, i))`
I'm still getting spaces in the export.

Comment: It works on your sample file by merely changing replacing the `Trim` function with the `NumberFormat` function.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you Ron. That seems to do it. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread but am replying in the event someone finds this in the future.

I have a sheet in Excel with 9 columns that contains currency exchange rates.  This gets updated monthly then VBA exports the new rates to a CSV and uploads them to an Access database that is my currency exchange rate source when needed.

Two of my column headers had a trailing space after creation of the CSV.  The two columns had the exchange rates and were formatted to have 4 decimal places.  I had also formatted the header text the same.  The trailing space was not apparent in the formula bar but was after CSV creation.  I updated the column format to General and the trailing space no longer appears in the CSV.